# Can't seem to get my 'while True' loop to keep looping

Tags: python

I'm making a little guess a number game and I have a 'while True' loop that I want to keep looping until the user guesses the correct number. Right now I have the number displayed for ease of testing. Whether I guess the correct number or not though, I get an error **" 'Nonetype' object has no attribute 'Guess'."** Im confused why the 'while True' has no error the first time it loops but an error is brought up after that.

**Tracker.py**

```
from Number import *

class Runner(object):
def __init__(self, start):
    self.start = start
    print Integer.__doc__
    print Integer.code

def play(self):
    next_guess = self.start

    while True:
        next_guess = next_guess.Guess()

        if next_guess == Integer.code:
            print "Good!"
            exit(0)

        else:
            print "Try again!"

Integer = Random_Integer()

Game = Runner(Integer)

Game.play()
```

**Number.py**

```
from random import randint

class Random_Integer(object):

"""Welcome to the guessing game! You have unlimited attempts
to guess the 3 random numbers, thats pretty much it."""

def __init__(self):
    self.code = "%d%d%d" % (randint(1,9), randint(1,9), randint(1,9))
    self.prompt = '> '

def Guess(self):
    guess_code = raw_input(self.prompt)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `.Guess()` method doesn't return anything:

```
def Guess(self):
    guess_code = raw_input(self.prompt)
```

You need to add a `return` statement there:

```
def Guess(self):
    guess_code = raw_input(self.prompt)
    return guess_code
```

When a function doesn't have an explicit return statement, it's return value is always `None`. Thus, the line:

```
next_guess = next_guess.Guess()
```

sets `next_guess` to `None`.

However, even if `.Guess()` *does* return it's `raw_input()` result, you now have replaced `next_guess` with a string result, and your next iteration through the loop will now fail because string objects do not have a `.Guess()` method.

You are also referring to a global `Integer` value everywhere, after passing it in as an argument to your `Runner()` instance, storing it as `self.start` there. Don't rely on globals, you already have `self.start`:

```
class Runner(object):
    def __init__(self, start):
        self.start = start
        print start.__doc__
        print start.code

    def play(self):        
        while True:
            next_guess = self.start.Guess()

            if next_guess == self.start.code:
                print "Good!"
                exit(0)

            else:
                print "Try again!"
```

In the above code we dispense with accessing the `Integer` global, instead using `self.start`. The `next_guess` variable is strictly used to hold the current guess, and we use `self.start.Guess()` instead.

Comment: Worth noticing: the OP's code will still break after the first guess, because once `Guess` returns the guess value, he'll still be trying to call `Guess` on a string, rather than a `Random_Integer`. He needs to either have `Guess` return `self` (and store the guess someplace) or more likely, just have the `Random_Integer` instance stored elsewhere so it's not overwritten, like `self.guesser = Random_Integer()` and then `next_guess = self.guesser.Guess()` in the loop.

Comment: I'm talking about the second time through the loop, when `next_guess` is a string and he tries to call `Guess()` on it. He needs it to be `next_guess = Integer.Guess()` instead.